# c# get all keys which does not have matching values in two dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq

Compare two dictionaries and get all "keys" which exist in both the dictionaries but have different "values" using linq 
for example.

```
var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"b", "2"},
    {"c", "3"}
};

var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"b", "22"},
    {"c", "33"}
};

output should be 
var DictionaryItems=new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"b", "2"},
    {"c", "3"}
};
```

here key b has 2 in one dictinary and 22 in second dictionary

Comment: So, keep going you have a start..

Comment: This sounds a little like homework..

Comment: So where's the question?

Comment: `var DictionaryItems = Dictionary1.Where(a => Dictionary2.ContainsKey(a.Key) && Dictionary2[a.Key] != a.Value);`

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Requirements are clear. Attempt has been included. Title is good for search results. Sure it could be better written, but it's pretty clear what is being asked

Comment: @musefan - I didn't downvote, but my guess would be it's something that can be easily searched and an answer found. Also, whilst an attempt has been made, it's not stated what issue they're now having. Whilst this is obvious to most, it basically shows little effort being put into the question. Still, as you say it's fairly clear what they want.

Comment: @musefan - you're right. I did a quick skim read of the potential duplicate. Now removed.

Comment: How do you want to be comparing the keys? Are they strings? If so are you worried about case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your keys are strings, here's a full, working, copy-paste-able example.

```
var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"b", "2"},
    {"c", "3"}
};

var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"b", "22"},
    {"c", "33"}
};

var result = dictionary1
    .Where(d => dictionary2.ContainsKey(d.Key) && dictionary2[d.Key] != d.Value);
```

This will return the following

[image]

If you want just the keys that are different, you can do

```
var result = dictionary1
  .Where(d => dictionary2.ContainsKey(d.Key) && dictionary2[d.Key] != d.Value)  
  .Select(d=> d.Key);
```

Which now will return

[image]